# SQL Query Ailas issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my question. I'm just not even sure where I should start.
List the first name, last name, and title of each employee, as well as the first name, lastname, and title of their supervisor; employees without supervisors should have null for theirsupervisor values.  Alias only the columns for the supervisor toSuperFirst,SuperLast,andSuperTitle; columns should be ordered asFirstName,LastName,Title,SuperFirst,SuperLast, andSuperTitle.

Here's the ER Diagram:

[image: Here's the ER Diagram]

Comment: please share your efforts, otherwise your homework won't get done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the question here? Please provide a clear question for us to work with.
Example Below for reference.

LEFT Join return all Employees all results that have a supervisor and ones that don't. The ones that don't would have a NULL value in the "S.*" columns. That should accomplish what you need.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Title, S.FirstName AS SuperFirst, S.LastName AS SupertLast, S.Title AS SuperTitle
FROM dbo.Employee E
LEFT JOIN dbo.Employee S ON E.ReportsTo = S.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Sorry here's the (query)question. "List the first name, last name, and title of each employee, as well as the first name, lastname, and title of their supervisor; employees without supervisors should have null for theirsupervisor values. Alias only the columns for the supervisor toSuperFirst,SuperLast,andSuperTitle; columns should be ordered asFirstName,LastName,Title,SuperFirst,SuperLast, andSuperTitle."

Comment: That's the whole question I guess my main problem is I don't understand how to relate employees and their supervisors because I don't see any supervisor attribute.

Comment: I'm not seeing a Supervisors table in your ER diagram, and the fields are not properly named to show clear table relationship.

For Example: If an Employee Table is Linked to Customer Table, the Employee Table will have a primary key of "ID", and it's foreign key in Customer Table would be labled "Employee ID". That is general SQL standard.

Comment: Admittedly your ER diagram makes this much harder than it's supposed to be.

Comment: Just for example sake, this would be a way of doing that kind of sql query if the tables were related in such a way edited in question.

Comment: Well thanks for looking at it. It is the last question of my homework so I didn't make the er diagram.

Comment: It looks like report to could be the supervisor field?

Comment: If that is the case, then it's just a join upon itself. I'll update my original answer to reflect what the query would be.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a self-join on `Employee` Table as below as it references itself.

```
SELECT emp.FirstName
    ,emp.LastName
    ,emp.Title
    ,super.FirstName as SuperFirst
    ,super.LastName as SuperLast
    ,super.Title as SuperTitle
FROM employee emp
LEFT JOIN employee super ON emp.reportsto = super.EmployeeId
ORDER BY 1
    ,2
    ,3
    ,4
    ,5
    ,6;
```

`Left join` will put `null` in Supervisor columns if no matching values are retrieved.

Comment: How would the ORDER BY impact this query?

Comment: @JohnW: In your question, you mentioned that data should be ordered by FirstName,LastName,Title,SuperFirst,SuperLast, andSuperTitle. so it sort data respectively.

Comment: @JohnW: WA E's query will fail with  "FirstName column is ambiguous"

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned before, when LEFT JOIN you should be able get NULL when there is no match. This code should work!

```html
SELECT Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName, Employee.Title, Emp.FirstName AS SuperFirst, Emp.LastName AS SuperLast, Emp.Title AS SupperTitle
FROM Employee LEFT JOIN Employee AS Emp ON Employee.ReportsTo = EmployeeTwo.EmployeeId
```

[image]